# possible memory leak due to DB close

Tags: node.js, mongodb, memory-leaks

I am trying to execute a function with setInterval but I am getting 2 errors the first is

```
node:88454) [MONGODB DRIVER] Warning: the options [servers] is not supported
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
(node:88454) [MONGODB DRIVER] Warning: the options [caseTranslate] is not supported
(node:88454) [MONGODB DRIVER] Warning: the options [dbName] is not supported
```

and the second is

```
(node:88384) MaxListenersExceededWarning: Possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 newListener listeners added to [MongoClient]. Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit
```

I don't think that increasing the `setMaxListeners` is the answer I think it has to do with closing the client how to i solve this? Codee below:

client:

```
const client = new MongoClient(cred.dbUri, {useUnifiedTopology: true})
```

concerned func:

```
async function delete90(){
    await client.connect(()=>{})
    const dataB = client.db("AmerKorAsian");
    const coll = dataB.collection("users");
    await coll.deleteMany({
        "Full Name":"",
        "Contact.Country":"",
        "Contact.Number":""
    })
 
   console.log("interval")
}



setInterval(delete90, 1000);//777600000


  

client.close()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem - you're creating a new connection every time.

Solution - connect once and cache the connection

**Option 1**

```
let connection;
async function connect() {
if(!connection)  {
   await client.connect(()=>{});
   connection = client.db;
 }
    return connection;
}

async function delete90(){
    const db = connect();
    const dataB = db("AmerKorAsian");
    const coll = dataB.collection("users");
    await coll.deleteMany({
        "Full Name":"",
        "Contact.Country":"",
        "Contact.Number":""
    })
 
   console.log("interval")
}
```

---

**Option 2**

```
let usersCollection;
async function getUserCollection() {
    if(!usersCollection) {
        await client.connect(()=>{});
        const dataB = client.db("AmerKorAsian");
        usersCollection = dataB.collection("users");
    }
    return usersCollection; // cache and return the collection
}

async function delete90(){
    const coll = await getUserCollection();
    await coll.deleteMany({
        "Full Name":"",
        "Contact.Country":"",
        "Contact.Number":""
    })
 
   console.log("interval")
}
```

Comment: i get this     const dataB = db("AmerKorAsian");
                  ^

TypeError: db is not a function
    at Timeout.delete90 [as _onTimeout] (/Users/amerkorasian/back.js:138:19)

Comment: option 2 i put const dataB = client.db("AmerKorAsian"); its working

Comment: Updated answer, please check